# Write to a different part of VS statusbar from extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions

In my extension I'd like to be able to show some text in the VS status bar all the time, so I can't use "alert" part (the leftmost area), since anybody (VS/other extensions) can overwrite it.

It seems that [`IVsStatusbar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsstatusbar.settext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't have such a facility, it only has `SetText(string)` which sets the alert area. However, ReSharper is able to use rightmost area as well, it puts its code inspection info there.

Is there a way either to write to a different area of the status bar, or to hook up into process of setting the text of it (so I could append all the incoming text after my block)?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same requirement which I [asked](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a5bffdf0-a111-45f4-946c-0f90af0f2174/how-to-display-text-in-different-color-on-the-right-hand-side-of-the-vs-statusbar?forum=vsx#b49fcdca-c8cf-4632-b8db-29eb0ce52456) in MSDN Forum. I was told it is not possible through SDK.

Comment: it seems that they have only answered the question part about coloring